# gwt-g2d: How to detect if point is in shape?

Tags: java, gwt, shapes, point-in-polygon

I'm trying to detect if a point is within an gwt-g2d shape.
Does anybody know how this is possible?

I just can determine if the point is within any path in the context.

Lets say I have a context with two rectangle (A & B) and want to determine in which rectangle the mouse is, how can I do this?

```
 ________________________
|   _______    _______   |
|  |       |  |       |  |
|  |   A   |  |   B   |  |
|  |_______|  |_______|  |
|________________________|
```

The rectangles were just examples, I also want to determine if the point is in complex shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look up the [point-in-polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) problem.  If you have a lot of polygons people also tend to narrow down the possibilities by storing the left,right,bottom, and top-most points of a polygon (or storing the radius and center point of a circle enclosing the polygon) so that they can quickly determine whether the point could even possibly be inside the polygon.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but i'm search for an build-in function, because if I add an arc via g2d it's possible it will have other points than my claculatet arc.

Answer (score 0):

after some trying I found a solution by editing the gwt-g2d source.

gwt-g2d create for each Surface an div with an canvas.
now i changed the the Surface to only create an canvas with position:absolute. now i just create multiple canvas and use its function IsPointInPath.

Chnages in Surface.java:

```
    public Surface(int width, int height) {
            canvas = Document.get().createElement("canvas").cast();
            setElement(Document.get().createDivElement());
            getElement().appendChild(canvas);
            canvasInitializer.init(canvas, width, height);
            setStylePrimaryName("g2d-Surface");
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            context = canvas.getContext2D();
    }
```

TO:

```
public Surface(int width, int height) {
    canvas = Document.get().createElement("canvas").cast();
    canvas.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;");
    setElement(canvas);
    canvasInitializer.init(canvas, width, height);
    setStylePrimaryName("g2d-Surface");
    this.width = width;     
    this.height = height;
    context = canvas.getContext2D();
}
```